# How CGI environment variables are passed to called programs?

Tags: http, server, cgi

It's obvious we have stdin and stout for input (http request headers and body) and stdout for response. But I cannot find clean explanation of the mechanism used for passing values like 'SCRIPT_NAME' or 'PATH' over CGI protocol. Probably it is more general question about environment variables at whole (which seems different things at first). 
Where are CGI variables fetching from?

Comment: Do you wonder how the web-server sets the variables for your program? Or how to fetch them *in* your program? For the latter (how to fetch them in your program) then you need to give us more, like what language you're programming in.

Comment: I wonder what is mechanism so both sides are of interest, how server set them for individual instance of called program and how program (where) does read it. I know language specific "sugar" doing task and I just want to know what happens under the hood.

Comment: That's really to broad. A few things you could research yourself though are how to parse `GET` and `POST` parameters; How processes works; And how a parent process can set environment variables of a child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http server process spawns a child process which runs your CGI script. It passes the http headers as environment variables to the handling child process. You can do the same thing in a C++ program of yours if you like. Just do CreateProcess (under windows) and set up the environment of the new child process. Then run it!